# Set Output Stream of specific JShell

Tags: java, eval, jshell, printstream

I have a code :

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World from main!");
        JShell shell = JShell.builder().build();
        shell.eval("System.out.println(\"Hello World from JShell!\");");

    }
}
```

Now I want that I can set the output stream for the JShell only and not the normal code.

I tried :

```
shell.eval("System.setOut(new Printer());");
shell.eval("System.out.println(\"Hello World!\");");
```

But does not work!

My Printer class:

```
class Printer extends PrintStream{
    public Printer() {
        super(System.out);
    }

    @Override
    public void print(String s) {
        super.print("Message: - " + s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to make JShell use the "local" `executionEngine`, so that you have access to your `Printer`:

```
JShell shell = JShell.builder().executionEngine("local").build();
```

This basically means "the same JVM".

Second, remember to import the `Printer` class, or use its fully qualified name, because `Printer` is probably not in the the same package as where JShell code is running (a package called `REPL` from my experiments).

It seems like your `Printer` class is not public, so you should make it `public` as well.